# why doesn't kafka support simple username/password authorization like activemq?

Tags: authorization, apache-kafka, kerberos

Since V0.9.0.0, Apache kafka add authorization support by using SASL(http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_sasl ), but it's too complex and confused to config Kerberos and jaas. So, why doesn't kafka support simple username/password authorization like activemq? It will be easy to use.

Comment: That's **authentication**, not authorization. If you cannot tell the difference, then I'm afraid you are not in a very good position to challenge the security options of Apache committers...

Comment: By the way, you can also use PKI authentication (using X509 certificates + private keys in a Java keystore) but that requires enabling SSL http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_configclients

Comment: In fact， I'm doing a "Kafka as a Service".  I create  a big kafka cluster pool and assign each tenant a single cluster.  All my need is that ensure each tenant can only use their own cluster.  So I think give their an username/paasword pair is a simplest way.

Comment: Well, if your "tenants" have strong security policies to enforce because of regulations (finance, health...) or just because they are cautious, they may raise an eyebrow on passwords -- unless you enforce rules about pwd strength, pwd renewal, disable-account-on-multiple-failed-attempts, etc. -- plus, you provide audit trails with reports and alerts. On the other hand, if your "tenants" just don't care or don't objectively need that, then you should be fine with the PLAIN stuff out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 4):

Kafka 0.10, just released yesterday, now supports `SASL/PLAIN` in addition to the previously supported SASL Kerberos (`GSSAPI`). `SASL/PLAIN` is effectively what you want. Take a look here:

http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/kafka/sasl.html

Comment: It seems suitable for me, I will try it.